# Proper way of adding resources dynamically to CoAP server

Tags: java, iot, coap, californium

I created a method which can be used for adding dynamically URLs into CoAP server.This is the current approach I have implemented. But needs to know is this the proper way of adding resources into the CoAP server? Let's say **coapendpoints/home/room1/sensor1** is the one which needs to be added.

```
    // endpoint--> coapendpoints/home/room1/sensor1
    String[] resources = endpoint.split("/");
    Resource childResource = coapServer.getRoot().getChild(resources[0]);
    Resource parentResource = childResource;
    if (parentResource == null && (resources.length > 1)) {
        coapServer.add(new CoAPResourcePath(resources));
    }
    if (parentResource == null && (resources.length == 1)) {
        coapServer.add(new CoAPResourceServlet(resources[0]));
    } else if (parentResource != null && resources.length > 1) {
        int j = 1;
        for (; j < resources.length; j++) {
            if (childResource != null) {
                parentResource = childResource;
                childResource = childResource.getChild(resources[j]);
            } else {
                break;
            }
        }
        String[] coapEndpoint = Arrays.copyOfRange(resources, j - 1, resources.length);
        if (coapEndpoint.length > 1) {
            parentResource.add(new CoAPResourcePath(coapEndpoint));
        } else if (coapEndpoint.length == 1) {
            parentResource.add(new CoAPResourceServlet(coapEndpoint[0]));
        }
    } else if (parentResource != null && resources.length == 1) {
        parentResource.add(new CoAPResourceServlet(resources[0]));
    }
```

Here CoAPResourcePath and CoAPResourceServlet classes are extended from CoapResource.

This is the output after adding resources in this way.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I've ended up with the similar approach. Currently Californium does not have any options for creating nested resources in a handy way.